# Remove Feed chatter in community

Tags: community, chatter, profile, chatter-feed, chatter-feed-tracking

Does anyone knows how I can remove the chatter in community for user profile. I don't want that shows up.
Please see the attachment, thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are trying to modify the User Profile component. Unfortuantely, you will have to create your own lightning component if you wish to remove certain fucntions. Standard lightning components are like little blackboxes, what you see is what you get.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking that maybe I can set it up from profile setting but actually I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

You can`t, but you can change this deafult component.
Delete default componente, and search for this, User Profile Detail.

[image]

[image]